# How to convert list of dictionaries into list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts and i want to make separate list of each key in dicts. The keys of the dicts are the same.
This is an example below:

convert this:

```
myList = [{'a':0,'b':2},{'a':1,'b':3}]
```

to:

```
newList = [[0,1],[2,3]]
```

Comment: Order in dictionaries is arbitrary; are you expecting a specific ordering here?

Comment: The order doesn't important but shouldn't be random!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find this site that use blew code:
[How to convert a list of dictionaries to a list of lists in Python](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-convert-list-of-dictionaries-to/)

```
[[row[key] for row in myList] for key in keylist]
```

Test:

```
def bycol_decl(lod, keylist):
    return  [[row[key] for row in lod] for key in keylist]

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    lod = [
        {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},
        {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6},
        {'a':7, 'b':8, 'c':9},
        ]
    keylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    print bycol_decl(lod, keylist)
```

Results:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `dict.values()` within a list comprehension to get the values and then use `zip` in order to get the columns :

```
>>> zip(*[d.values() for d in myList])
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

If you want list of list :

```
>>> [list(col) for col in zip(*[d.values() for d in myList])]
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: list of list is wanted

Comment: @VigneshKalai: This is easily enough converted, and may not be a hard requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to know list order? at least I want to have alphabetic order!

Comment: @MOHRE In that case you need to get the keys and values with `dict.items()` method and sort the list based on keys then get the values.

Comment: ok but is there any solution with preknown order? (e.g. like solution I post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdefault` to get a new dictionary `d` then print the `d.values`

```
d = {}
for e in myList:
    for i,j in e.items():
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
newList = d.values()
print (newList)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```