# Function to Parse Arrays in JSON to Insert Into a SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, json

Trying to take a web API's JSON response and populate a SQL database with the results.

Part of the JSON response has this array:

```
"MediaLinks": [
            {
                "MediaType": "Datasheets",
                "SmallPhoto": "",
                "Thumbnail": "",
                "Title": "SN54HC374, SN74HC374",
                "Url": "http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74hc374"
            },
            {
                "MediaType": "Product Photos",
                "SmallPhoto": "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP_sml.jpg",
                "Thumbnail": "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP_tmb.jpg",
                "Title": "20-DIP,R-PDIP-Txx",
                "Url": "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP.jpg"
            },
            {
                "MediaType": "Featured Product",
                "SmallPhoto": "",
                "Thumbnail": "",
                "Title": "Logic Solutions",
                "Url": "https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/logic-solutions "
            },
            {
                "MediaType": "Featured Product",
                "SmallPhoto": "",
                "Thumbnail": "",
                "Title": "Analog Solutions",
                "Url": "https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/analog-solutions "
            },
            {
                "MediaType": "PCN Design/Specification",
                "SmallPhoto": "",
                "Thumbnail": "",
                "Title": "Copper Bond Wire Revision A 04/Dec/2013",
                "Url": "http://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Texas%20Instruments/PCN20120223003A_Copper-wire.pdf"
            },
            {
                "MediaType": "PCN Design/Specification",
                "SmallPhoto": "",
                "Thumbnail": "",
                "Title": "Material Set 30/Mar/2017",
                "Url": "http://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Texas%20Instruments/PCN20170310000.pdf"
            }
        ],
```

For testing I've issued the request and then written the response to a file and I'm experimenting with this file to come up with the correct code

```
conn.request("POST", "/services/partsearch/v2/partdetails", json.dumps(payload), headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

data_return = json.loads(data)
print(json.dumps(data_return, indent=4))

with open(y["DigiKeyPartNumber"]+".json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data_return, write_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
write_file.close()
```

Then in my test code I've tried this:

```
import json

with open(r"C:\Users\george\OneDrive\Documents\296-1592-5-ND.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

values = ""
placeholder = '?'
thelist = []
thelist = list(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'])
print(type(thelist))
#print(thelist)

placeholders = ', '.join(placeholder for unused in (data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']))
query = 'INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(%s)' % placeholders
print(query)
```

But this just produces the following output:

```
<class 'list'>
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

For reference this creates what I think will work except for the trailing comma:

```
if len(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']):
    print('The length is: ' + str(len(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'])))
    #print(type(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']))
    for mediadata in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']:
        #print(mediadata)
        for element in mediadata:
            #print(element + ' is "' + mediadata[element] + '"')
            values += '"' + mediadata[element] + '", '
    #print(list(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'][1]))
        print(values + "\n")
        values = ""
else:
    print('It is empty')
```

Which produces this:

```
The length is: 6
"Datasheets", "", "", "SN54HC374, SN74HC374", "http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74hc374",

"Product Photos", "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP_sml.jpg", "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP_tmb.jpg", "20-DIP,R-PDIP-Txx", "http://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/296-20-DIP.jpg",

"Featured Product", "", "", "Logic Solutions", "https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/logic-solutions ",

"Featured Product", "", "", "Analog Solutions", "https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/analog-solutions ",

"PCN Design/Specification", "", "", "Copper Bond Wire Revision A 04/Dec/2013", "http://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Texas%20Instruments/PCN20120223003A_Copper-wire.pdf",

"PCN Design/Specification", "", "", "Material Set 30/Mar/2017", "http://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Texas%20Instruments/PCN20170310000.pdf",
```

In the table I've created in SQL it uses the same column names as the keys in the JSON array. There are several arrays in the JSON response so I'm hoping to create a generic function that accepts the JSON array and creates the correct SQL INSERT statements to populate the tables with the JSON data. I'm planning on using pyodbc and best case is something that works for both Python 2.7 as well as 3.x

Updated Information:

I found the following code snippet which comes very close:

```
for thedata in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']:
    keys, values = zip(*thedata.items())
    print(values) #This will create the VALUES for the INSERT Statement
print(keys) #This will create the COLUMNS, need to add the PartDetailsId field
```

I was trying to find a way to get the keys before I ran this for loop because I would have to replace the print statements with the actual SQL INSERT statement.

When I check `type(newdata['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'])` is returns `<class 'list'>` in Python 3.7.4 so even though it looks like a dictionary it's treated like a list and .keys() fails to try and grab the keys

Comment: I don't see a question here. What problem are you having? If you're having trouble creating that generic function, show what you've tried so far and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I posted too much. The last code I posted is kind of a brute force which comes close but adds a final comma which would have to be removed.

The "test code" section with the placeholder variable is my attempt to try and be smarter about the data but that produced an empty field (the VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: Why are you putting the data into strings? You've correctly created the query with placeholders. Call `cursur.execute(query, values)` where `values` is one of the elements of the `MediaLinks` list.

Comment: You can also use `executemany()` and give it the entire list, and it will iterate over it automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I was looking at executemany() but haven't tried it yet. [MedialInks] contains both the column names and the values so I wasn't sure how to structure the query. The other issue is that for each record I also need to add in the main database key (PartDetailsId). The complete JSON response is at https://pastebin.com/81iuy60i. What I did was create a main table and then every "array" in the JSON response is a table that is linked by the PartDetailsId field

Answer (score 0):

Use `cursor.executemany()` to execute the query on all the rows in the `MediaLinks` list.

You can't pass the dictionaries directly, though, because iterating over a dictionary returns the keys, not the values. You need to convert this to a list of values, using one of the methods in [How to convert list of dictionaries into list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283627/how-to-convert-list-of-dictionaries-into-list-of-lists)

```
colnames = ", ".join (data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'][0].keys())
placeholders = ", ".join(["?"] * len(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'][0]))
query = "INSERT INTO MediaLInks (" + colnames + ") VALUES (" + placeholders + ")"
cursor.executemany(query, [tuple(d.values()) for d in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']])
```

Comment: I tried your example and it returns an error:
`
cursor.executemany(query, (d.values() for d in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']))
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
`
Which is what I've been fighting from the beginning.

Comment: I've changed it to a list comprehension, I think that should solve it.

Comment: Thank you @Barnar very much for working with me, I do appreciate it. Even your modified statement still returns the same error though, `  File "c:\Users\george\OneDrive\Documents\JSONFileTest.py", line 80, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(query, [d.values() for d in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']])
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')`

Comment: I thought it would accept an iterator. I've called `tuple()`.

Comment: That's getting much closer. I'm getting invalid column names so I'm double checking the structure

Comment: My query variable looks like this: `>>> query
"INSERT INTO MediaLinks ('MediaType', 'SmallPhoto', 'Thumbnail', 'Title', 'Url') VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"` and my table was created with:
`CREATE TABLE dbo.MediaLinks
(
MediaLinksId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
PartDetailsId int NULL,
MediaType nvarchar(40) NULL,
SmallPhoto nvarchar(100) NULL,
Thumbnail nvarchar(100) NULL,
Title nvarchar(60) NULL,
Url nvarchar(100) NULL
)'
But all the columns return this error `Invalid column name 'MediaType'`

Comment: OK, I thought I had checked the lengths of the data and padded so the table column lengths were enough but I needed to make the table column lengths longer. The other issue is I was trying to create the table names but when I did they were passed in quotes and I need to figure out how to remove the quotes so I just make a list of column names that can be inserted into the SQL statement. For now I just hard coded the SQL statement. I also need to figure out how to insert the PartDetailsId field into the list you created

Comment: So I was able to insert the PartId field rather easily by changing the query to:`#query = "INSERT INTO MediaLinks " + str(keys) + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
query = "INSERT INTO MediaLinks (PartDetailsId, MediaType, SmallPhoto, Thumbnail, Title, Url) VALUES(" + str(data['PartDetails']['PartId']) +", ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"` Now I just need to figure out how to pass the column names (without quotes) into the query statement so they don't have to be hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I want to post a formatted code snippet that is working for me. This would not have been possible without @barmar 's help so thanks again.

The end goal is to convert this into a function so that I can pass in the arrays from a JSON response and have it populate the correct SQL tables with the data. This is close to being complete but not quite there yet.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=GEORGE-OFFICE3\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=Components;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

with open(r"C:\Users\george\OneDrive\Documents\296-1592-5-ND.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

x = tuple(data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks'][0])
a = str(x).replace("'","").replace("(","")

query = "INSERT INTO MediaLinks (PartDetailsId, " + a + " VALUES(" + str(data['PartDetails']['PartId'])

b = ""
for i in range(len(x)):
    b += ", ?"
b += ")"

query += b

cursor.executemany(query, [tuple(d.values()) for d in data['PartDetails']['MediaLinks']])
cursor.commit()

conn.close()
```